# How can we populate other form fields by updating a specific field from table sources in ms-access using code builder only

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have the below problem:

- I have a student table in access with field class, classfee and leaves
- and another table namely classes with fields class, monthlyfee and leaves
- I have related both tables with a one to many relationship
- now i have created a form as shown in images and i want when i choose class from the drop
  down box the leave and fee field should come up automatically from the classes table
  fields (monthlyfee and leaves)

Problem explained in this image

[image]

Code explained here

[image]

tables relationship here

[image]

```
Private Sub Class_AfterUpdate()

Me.Fee.RowSource = "SELECT ClassFee FROM" & _
                   "Classes Where Class_ID = " & Me.Class

Me.Fee = Me.Fee.ItemData(0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the error message that probably tells about a syntax error, as you missed the space here:

```
Me.Fee.RowSource = "SELECT ClassFee FROM " & _
               "Classes Where Class_ID = " & Me.Class
```

Comment: There is no error message just it does not work as mentioned in the picture dear Gustav